# I want the tab-contents to be displayed according to the tab being clicked using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing difficulty to display the tab contents when the corresponding tab is being clicked. this is my code but it fails to work as per my requirement. when I click on the Eat tab, all the values of the array are repeating. please help me out!!

```
<script>


  $(function() {
          $("#tabbable").tabs();
         }); 

    var i;
    var mytabs = new Array();
    mytabs[0] = "Saab";
    mytabs[1] = "Volvo";
    mytabs[2] = "BMW";

    </script>
    <body>
    <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span1 offset1">
                <div class="tabbable" align="center">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">



          <li class="active"><a href="#tabs-1" data-toggle="tab">Eat</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tabs-2">Drink</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>  
    </div>
    <div id="1"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $("a[href=#tabs-1]").click(function()
            {

          for (i=0;i<mytabs.length;i++)
            {
              $('div').append("<br>"+mytabs[i]+"<br>");
        }
        });</script>

    </body>
```

Comment: what framework do you use for the tab functionality? Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6JVjA/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $(".tabbable").tabs();
});
```

**NOT** `$("#tabbable").tabs();`

***or***

```
<div id="tabbable" class="tabbable" align="center">
```

then display the tab contents using ".ui-widget-content"

```
for (i=0;i<mytabs.length;i++)
{
     $(".ui-widget-content").append("<br>"+mytabs[i]+"<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/uZRPd/

HTML

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#saab">Saab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#volvo">Volvo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#bmw">BMW</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="saab">
        <p>Content for Saab</p>
    </div>
    <div id="volvo">
        <p>Content for Volvo</p>
    </div>
    <div id="bmw">
        <p>Content for BMW</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
```

Note that you need to include Jquery UI (both CSS and JS) apart from Jquery to make it work.